# Derivative of an implicit function

Tags: calculus

I am asked to take the derivative of the following equation for $y$:

$$y = x + xe^y$$

However, I get lost. I thought that it would be

$$\begin{align}
& y' = 1 + e^y + xy'e^y\\
& y'(1 - xe^y) = 1 + e^y\\
& y' = \frac{1+e^y}{1-xe^y}
\end{align}$$

However, the text book gives me a different answer. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you and sorry if I got any terms wrong, my math studies were not done in English... :)

Comment: I think you need to tell us what different answer the book gave. There are many possible answers which look different but are actually equivalent to each other.

Comment: Looks good to me. What answer does the book give?

Comment: The book says: y/(x(1+x-y))

Comment: $$\frac{1+e^y}{1-xe^y} = \frac{x(1+e^y)}{x(1-xe^y)} = \frac{y}{x(1+x-y)}.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify things as follows:

$$y' = \frac{1+e^y}{1-xe^y} = \frac{x+xe^y}{x(1-xe^y)} = \frac{y}{x(1-y+x)}$$

Here in the last step we used $y=x+xe^y$ and $xe^y=y-x$.

Comment: Great, got it! :) Thank you!